# 'Would' in imagined situations

Tags: modal-verbs

I recently learnt that 'would' is used to talk about imagined or possible situations.

Let us take an example for an imagined situation:

***"One day, he would become the biggest striker in the history of football."***

How will the sentence be affected if we use 'will' instead of 'would' in this sentence?

Comment: That is not an imagined situation.  An imagined situation is along the lines of: If I had a billion dollars I would buy a small island.

Comment: The man who would be King.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "would" is simply the past of "will".

> One day, he will become the biggest striker ...

is simply a prediction: it might or might not come true, but we cannot tell at present.

In the past,

> One day, he would become the biggest striker ...

is a prediction from a point in the past. The people at that point could not know whether or not it would come true; but because of our viewpoint, we might know. (We might not yet know, because it might still come to pass; but we might, for example if he has died).

Comment: Is it write to say: "Tomorrow is a match between the two biggest rival teams. The stadium would be completely full."

Comment: @TheNOVICE (you mean 'right') Since the tickets are probably already sold by the day before, '*will*' is probably more appropriate here.  It has a degree of certainty to it.

Comment: @marcellothearcane   What if I am recounting from my past experience and not from any particular statistics?

Comment: @TheNOVICE yes, I'd probably still use 'will'.  Generally, I'd use 'would' if I was going to contradict it - e.g. "The stadium normally would be full, but it's pouring with rain", or similar.

Comment: Let me give you an example:

**An even that has already come to pass:**

_Donald Trump was so obnoxious, no one thought that he `would` become the president._

**An event which hasn't happened yet:** Doesn't have to be a fact, because it's about the future, it will not be a fact until it becomes the past.

_Donald Trump will be impeached by the end of the year._

Comment: This is an _imagined_ situation, as OP states. //  'One day, he will become the biggest striker ...' is talking about say Puskas when he was aged 12, but years later, with the hindsight of having seen his career when he retired at 40-odd.  '[Who could foresee that] One day, he would become the biggest striker ...' means very much the same. But there is another possibility with 'would': an imagined future (a future imagined in the past). 'He was not content to be mediocre. He would work hard at his exams and ...

Comment: become the greatest physicist since Einstein.' It is just about possible to use 'will' as a present-for-the-past with this sense also.